# Clear All Query Cache in Yii

Tags: php, caching, yii, query-cache

Following is the configuration Code for my DB cache in Yii

```
'dbcache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.db.CDbConnection',
            'connectionString'=>'sqlite:/' . str_replace('\\','/',str_replace('C:\\','',getcwd()).'/protected/data/cache.db'),
            ),
```

And the following is my code for getting the record set and setting in the cache:

```
$recordset = Table1::model ()->cache(0)->find ( "primary_id=:id", array (":id" => $id) );
```

I have used **0** for the cache duration because I need to make it for infinite period. 
Now I need to refresh my Cache. on some condition. How can I refresh the query Cache in Yii if its duration is infinite. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, setting the value as **0** doesn't mean that you are setting for Infinite Period. It does mean that you have simply **Disabled** the cache.

Refer the Code: [Class Reference - CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#cache-detail)

If you want to refresh the Schema Cache, use the code as `Yii::app()->schema->refresh()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be Yii::app()->db->schema->refresh() ? But it does not clear the cache!